# DataTables: Show action button depending on query

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatable

I have jquery DataTables to show data through an ajax call.
It all loads nicely and at the last column, I have added a action button which will add the data to another db.
But i cant seem to figure out how to solve one thing:
When the button has been pressed and the system has added the row data to the other db, i dont want to show the button again on reload.
I have figure that i of course need the id of all rows in my add-to-db, so i have made a db query returning all the row ids that has been added - but how can i check of the id matches a row in my table and then dont show the button for the row in dataTables?
Below you can see how i set up my DataTable:

```
var table = $('#user-table').DataTable({
    "destroy": true,
    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": false,
    "ajax": {
            "url": "myAjaxCall",
            "dataType": "json",
            "data": JSON.stringify(data()),
            "type": "GET",
            "dataSrc": "collection"
    },
    "columns": [
        {"data": "customerNumber"},
        {"data": "name"},
        {"data": "coNumber"},
        {"data": "city"},
        {"data": "email"},
        {"data": "balance"},
        {"data": null,
            "defaultContent": "<a href='#' class='myButton btn'>Add</a>",
            className: "center", "bSortable": false, "bSearchable": false}
    ]
});
```

I could really need some help on this one - first time with dataTables - i love it, but just need to get this one to the finish line :-)

Comment: Well, can you provide example of rendered HTML?

Comment: Is data responded in JSON format, for sure?

Comment: yes, they are responded in json. i will update html in a sec

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of rowCallback function.

```
var arrayOfAlreadyAddedRows = [1,5,7];  //Here is array you made from db.

"rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
    // I assume in your data you have a rowId column.

    if ( $.inArray(data.rowId, arrayOfAlreadyAddedRows ) !== -1 ) {
        $(row).find('td:eq(6)').html( "<a href='#' class='myButton btn'>Add</a>");
    }else{
       $(row).find('td:eq(6)').html("<b>Already added</b>");
    }
}
```

or you already mark added row in your table data. something like a column called 'added' with value yes/no/

```
"rowCallback": function( row, data ) {
    if (data.added === "yes") {
        $(row).find('td:eq(6)').html("<a href='#' class='myButton btn'>Add</a>");
    }else{
        $(row).find('td:eq(6)').html("<b>Already added</b>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for input with callback, can i place it anywhere in the initialization? The second solution will change everytime i do the ajax call? How does the inarray function work?

Comment: Yes you can put that in initialization. When you fetch the data from server for your table, rowCallback will be called, then in your data you have indication which row is added and which not. In first option before table is init. you make an array of already added rows.

Comment: my arrayOfAlreadyAddedRows is returned as an json array - can i use it like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a renderfunction for your button; just add a columnDefs defintion to your DataTable initialization:  http://www.datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html

This allows you to make logical decisions before elements get rendered.

```
var table = $('#user-table').DataTable({ 
.....
         "columnDefs": [
          {
           // The `data` parameter refers to the data for the cell (defined by the
           // `data` option, which defaults to the column being worked with, in
           // this case `data: 6`.
           "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
            //in here you should check if your button was clicked - if the id matches the id of a button     that was already  clicked - if that's the case just return an empty string otherwhise return a button:
            if(buttonClicked) //you need to write that logic obviously
            {
                return "";
            }else {
                return "<a href='#' class='myButton btn'>Add</a>";
            }

             },
             "targets": 6 //adjust as needed
           }
```

Comment: ah ok - i will try this solution now. i guess its no problem to run a function and based on the dynamical return value render the output?

Comment: no - this is one of the use cases for it. You can even return a flag as part of your JSON (something clever liked clicked : false and then render based on the value of that flag. So you don't need to make another request for the clicked ids ... but that's up to you ;)

Comment: i see - clever :) But i get the data/ajax from another server, so i guess thats not the solution for me

Comment: you can still use the ajax from another server - get the ajax with the clicked ids from the other server first, then in your column renderfunction you can compare the current id to the list of ids you get returned

Comment: exactly thats what im trying to do now.